# Getting data with images from Remote DB to sqlite DB

Tags: php, android, mysql, image, sqlite

I'm making an android app that needs to get a table with 4 columns and 1 column is an image in BLOB format from a remote db into an sqlite db. Right now i can get all the info except the image column via JSON. But the images always come out as null. My code for the php page is

$q=mysql_query("SELECT * From Table WHERE FID>'".$_REQUEST['FID']."'");
        while($e=mysql_fetch_assoc($q))
                $output[]=$e;

print(json_encode($output));

mysql_close();
?>
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Without the DB, it's very difficult to be certain - a schema for the table would be useful.

First, I'd check the mysql (command-line) output for the same query, to see if it's null in the database.

Secondly, you'll need to massage the image data into a UTF8 friendly format - base64 will do. According to the [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) docs for the *value* field:

> This function only works with UTF-8
>   encoded data.

**EDIT**

- To encode the blob to base64, use [base64_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base64-encode.php) on the relevant field on the PHP end.
- To decode the JSON field back to a byte[] in the Android app, use [Base64.decode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#decode%28java.lang.String,%20int%29))

Comment: Ok i have verified the image is in there and made a new tables with just FID and Image, but the json is [{"FID":"1","Image":null}] etc. So how exactly do I massage it into a UTF8 friendly format? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: Thanks, I'm pretty sure I know how to get it into the android ap through base64 decode but I am a complete beginner when it comes to php so Im wondering how to isolate the image to encode it in my php file?

Comment: Change '$output[] = $e' to '{ $e['Image'] = base64_encode($e['Image']); $output[] = $e }'